# Ploting a Fourier rectangular signal in Matlab

Tags: fourier-series, matlab

For my homework I got this problem to solve.  I found the Fourier coeficients an and bn. 
*an=1/(n*pi)*sin(n.*pi);

bn=-1/(n*pi)*cos(n.*pi);
a0=1

*
for my rectangular signal starting in t=0 with amplitude A=1, filling factor 1ms and T=2ms . I tried to implement this in Matlab but he plots only dots (1,1)
ths is my code:
*T=0.002;tau=0.001;alfa=tau/T;A=1;f=1/T;

n=1:1:150;

an=1./(n.*pi).*sin(n.*pi);

bn=-1./(n.*pi).*cos(n.*pi);

t=0:0.01:3*T;

s=1+an.*cos(n*2*pi*f*t)+bn.*sin(n*2*pi*f*t);

plot(t,s);*

I'm pretty new in Matlab and Fourier series, I heard about them 1 week ago, so any help would be great.

Thank you :)